# Efficient algorithm to calculate values in data.frame without loop

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is the situation where I got kinda stuck with R. I have data table with one row for each day, something like this:

```
Date = c(as.Date("2015-12-31"), as.Date("2016-01-01"));
Month1 = c("DEC", "JAN");
Year1 = c("15", "16");
Price1 = c(100, 110);
Month2 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_);
Year2 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_);
Price2 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_);
Month3 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_);
Year3 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_);
Price3 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_);
Month4 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_);
Year4 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_);
Price4 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_);

dataSample = data.frame(Date, Month1, Year1, Price1, Month2, Year2, Price2, Month3, Year3, Price3, Month4, Year4, Price4);
```

Which gives such a table:

```
        Date Month1 Year1 Price1 Month2 Year2 Price2 Month3 Year3 Price3 Month4 Year4 Price4
1 2015-12-31    DEC    15    100   <NA>  <NA>     NA   <NA>  <NA>     NA   <NA>  <NA>     NA

2 2016-01-01    JAN    16    110   <NA>  <NA>     NA   <NA>  <NA>     NA   <NA>  <NA>     NA
```

Now I need to calculate all months and prices for each. For that I have 2 other data frames:

```
Date = c(as.Date("2015-12-31"), as.Date("2015-12-31"), as.Date("2015-12-31"), as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2016-01-01"));
Month.Start =  c("DEC", "JAN", "FEB", "JAN", "FEB", "MAR");
Year.Start =  c("15", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16")
Month.End =  c("JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "FEB", "MAR", "APR");
Year.End =  c("16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16")
Diff =  c(10, 15, -15, 19, -20, -5);


diffsOneMonth = data.frame(Date, Month.Start, Year.Start, Month.End, Year.End, Diff)

Date = c(as.Date("2015-12-31"), as.Date("2016-01-01"));
Month.Start =  c("DEC", "MAR");
Year.Start =  c("15", "16")
Month.End =  c("MAR", "JUN");
Year.End =  c("16", "16")
Diff =  c(11, 25);


diffsThreeMonth = data.frame(Date, Month.Start, Year.Start, Month.End, Year.End, Diff)
```

Which gives me these tables:

```
One month price differences
      Date          Month.Start Year.Start Month.End Year.End Diff
    1 2015-12-31         DEC         15       JAN       16   10
    2 2015-12-31         JAN         16       FEB       16   15
    3 2015-12-31         FEB         16       MAR       16  -15
    4 2016-01-01         JAN         16       FEB       16   19
    5 2016-01-01         FEB         16       MAR       16  -20
    6 2016-01-01         MAR         16       APR       16   -5

Three month price differences
            Date Month.Start Year.Start Month.End Year.End Diff
    1 2015-12-31         DEC         15       MAR       16   20
    2 2016-01-01         MAR         16       JUN       16   25
```

Now I must fill *dataSample* data frame by using data from differences tables. I check what start/end months/years are available there and have to fill those months/years in *dataSample*. Then take difference of price and set calculated price in *dataSample*. So for example in *dataSample* we start with DEC 15, then in *diffsOneMonth* we have entry DEC 15 - JAN 16 with difference 10 so we add it to DEC 15 price and get JAN 16 price 110:

```
    Date      Month1 Year1 Price1 Month2 Year2 Price2 Month3 Year3 Price3 Month4 Year4 Price4
1 2015-12-31    DEC    15    100   JAN   16     110   <NA>  <NA>     NA   <NA>  <NA>     NA
2 2016-01-01    JAN    16    110   <NA>  <NA>     NA   <NA>  <NA>     NA   <NA>  <NA>     NA
```

Now its possible to do next month and then next etc. If we use *diffsOneMonth* only we would get desirable result like this:

```
 Date             Month1 Year1 Price1 Month2 Year2 Price2 Month3 Year3 Price3 Month4 Year4 Price4
    1 2015-12-31    DEC    15    100   JAN   16     110     FEB  16     125      MAR  16     110
    2 2016-01-01    JAN    16    110   FEB   16     129     MAR  16     109      APR  16     104
```

However there is additional requirement that I must use wider month spread to calculate prices if its possible. So for 2015-12-31 there exists three month spread from DEC 15 to MAR 16 which should override price from one month difference. So DEC 15 price is 110 and DEC 15 - MAR 16 difference is 11 which makes MAR 16 price not 110 but 111:

```
      Date             Month1 Year1 Price1 Month2 Year2 Price2 Month3 Year3 Price3 Month4 Year4 Price4
        1 2015-12-31    DEC    15    100   JAN   16     110     FEB  16     125      MAR  16     111
        2 2016-01-01    JAN    16    110   FEB   16     129     MAR  16     109      APR  16     104
```

So for this sample it would be my final desirable output.
 Real data is much more complex, with 6 and 12 month differences and 64 months forward for each date. Also some months can be missing. I tried to do it with a loop but it was very slow, however I am not sure how to approach such a problem without a loop. I have created few helper methods to be able to calculate next year/month:

```
nextContract = function(currentMonth, currentYear, length = 1,
                        years = c("10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18"),
                        months = c("JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC")) {
  mIdx <- match(currentMonth, months)+length;
  yDiff = ifelse(length(months) < mIdx, mIdx / length(months) - ifelse(mIdx %% length(months) == 0, 1, 0), 0);
  return(data.frame(nextMonth(currentMonth, length, months), nextYear(currentYear, length = yDiff)))
}

nextYear = function(currentYear, length = 1, years = c("10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18")) {
  return(years[match(currentYear, years)+length]);
}

nextMonth = function(currentMonth, length = 1, months = c("JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC")) {
  mIdx <- match(currentMonth, months)+length;
  return(months[ifelse(length(months) < mIdx, ifelse(mIdx %% length(months) != 0, mIdx %% length(months), length(months)), mIdx)]);
}
```

Example of usage could be:

```
> nextContract("DEC", "15")
  nextMonth.currentMonth..length..months. nextYear.currentYear..length...yDiff.
1                                     JAN                                    16
```

or:

```
> nextContract("DEC", "15", length = 3)
  nextMonth.currentMonth..length..months. nextYear.currentYear..length...yDiff.
1                                     MAR                                    16
```

This got to be pretty long question but I hope someone will take time to review it :)

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
A little bit of improvement on proposed solution and I got what I needed:

```
    outrightAndForwardRows <- list("1" = diffsOneMonth, "3" = diffsThreeMonth) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "time_step") %>%
  left_join(dataSample %>%
              select(Date, Price1, Month1, Year1) ) %>%
  mutate(Day.Start = 1) %>%
  mutate(Day.End = 1) %>%
  mutate(Outright.Day = 1) %>%
  unite("Contract.Start", Day.Start, Month.Start, Year.Start) %>%
  unite("Contract.End", Day.End, Month.End, Year.End) %>%
  unite("Contract.Outright", Outright.Day, Month1, Year1) %>%
  mutate(time_step = as.numeric(time_step),
         Contract.Start =
           Contract.Start %>%
           parse_date_time("%d_%b_%y")) %>%
  mutate(Contract.End =
           Contract.End %>%
           parse_date_time("%d_%b_%y")) %>%
  mutate(Contract.Outright =
           Contract.Outright %>%
           parse_date_time("%d_%b_%y")) %>%
  group_by(time_step, Date) %>%
  arrange(Contract.End) %>%
  mutate(Price = cumsum(Diff) + Price1) %>%
  group_by(Date, Contract.End) %>%
  slice(time_step %>% which.max) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-time_step, -Diff, -Contract.Start)

#### add outright and forward months to the same columns
outright <- outrightAndForwardRows %>% select(Date, Price=Price1, Contract=Contract.Outright) %>% unique
forwardMonths <- outrightAndForwardRows %>% select(Date, Contract=Contract.End, Price)
# join and sort rows
joined <- rbind(outright, forwardMonths) %>% arrange(Date, Contract)
# add contract sequence
joined = data.table(joined)
joined = joined[, Contract.seq:=seq(.N), by=Date];

dcast(joined, Date ~ Contract.seq, value.var=c("Price", "Contract"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

list(`1` = diffsOneMonth,
    `3` = diffsThreeMonth) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "time_step") %>%
  left_join(dataSample %>%
              select(Date, Price1, Month1, Year1) ) %>%
  mutate(Day.Start = 1) %>%
  unite("Date.Start", Day.Start, Month.Start, Year.Start) %>%
  mutate(time_step = as.numeric(time_step),
         Date.Start =
           Date.Start %>%
           parse_date_time("%d_%b_%y")) %>%
  group_by(time_step, Date) %>%
  arrange(Date.Start) %>%
  mutate(Price = cumsum(Diff) + Price1) %>%
  group_by(Date, Date.Start) %>%
  slice(time_step %>% which.max)
```

Comment: Hmm thanks for the ideas. I do not get intended result (and not even close) but maybe something like this with dplyr can help me.

Comment: Ok finaly found some time and managed to do what I needed so I accept your answer as it put me on the right path :)